# Sort of multiple inheritance?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, design-patterns

I have the following class structure (Blah === ExtBlah):

```
Base
 +--[ ExtBase ]    --???-- [ ExtBlah ] --- .. more scripts ...
 +--[ Blah ]
        +---[ Script1 ]
        +---[ Script2 ]
        +---[ ....... ]
        +---[ ScriptN ]
```

Now I need to write more Scripts which need to extend Blah, but Blah has to extend "ExtBase", instead of "Base" for the new script cases.

I still have to have Blah the way it is because the Scripts1-N have to be dependent on "Base", not on "ExtBase".

Also I don't want to create a copy of Blah i.e. ExtBlah, because that mean duplication of code and will be harder and messier to support.

Any ideas ?

Comment: embed a Blah into ExtBlah to make it an adapter

Comment: Yeah, there's a [Delegation Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) that can be used here.  If you're using NetBeans `Alt-Ins` will bring up a menu that allows the methods to be automagically generated.

Comment: Also, Java doesn't have "scripts" so please don't call them that.  Probably you mean classes, but "source files" and "compilation units" might also be appropriate.

Comment: I cant embeed, because Base&ExtBase is part of a jar. I have access to the jar, but it is part of framework I dont want to pollute it.  thx

Comment: see aop (aspectj) declare parents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have a complication that the Base&ExtBase have init routines that prep db connections and other things which prevent me from instantiating multiple instances inheriting from Base.

Here is what I did.

Created a separate util-like class BaseUtil then in Blah&ExtBlah overrode init() like this :

```
 @Override
 public void init() {
   super.init();
   util = new BaseUtil(this.shared1, this.shared2, ....);
 }
```

/Now Blah extends Base, ExtBlah extends ExtBase and BaseUtil contains all shared functionality, but still can behave like Base because I pass all shared attributes, w/o the need to call init() twice/.

So the idea is to create instance of object which holds all shared functionality i.e. not duplicating code, but duplicating attributes instead.
BaseUtil is outside of the hierarchy.

PS> This will probably be awkward if you have too many shared attributes.
Also if you don't want to change the original scripts to use "util.method()" you can delegate all the methods.

Answer (score 1):

As Jean-Baptiste stated in his comment, if you dont'want to duplicate code of Blah encapsulate it into ExtBlah and invoke methods of Blah. Remember to add a common interface. In fact, interfaces try to solve some multiple inheritance issues.

```
Base
 +--[ ExtBase ]
 +--[ Blah ] implements BlahInterface
        +---[ Script1 ]
        +---[ Script2 ]
        +---[ ....... ]
        +---[ ScriptN ]   
 +--[ ExtBlah: - private Blah instance] implements BlahInterface
        +---[ ScriptK ]
```

Comment: there is one complication because Base&ExtBase have code that runs on initialization/construction. If what you are saying that I have to have private-instance this means I would have two initialization run, which is icky. but this gave me something to think about

Comment: If it's possible try to wrap Base into a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) class. In this way you instance the class Blah only once.